# Is there a cross-platform CD/DVD burning library or command-line app?

Tags: cross-platform, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I'm looking for a cross-platform CD & DVD burning library. I'm not too particular about the language or framework a long as there are minimal dependencies and they are easily installable cross-platform, or already exist.

A command-line application would also work..

Looking to target WinXP, Vista, Win7, OS X Leopard & Snow Leopard, & most linux distros.

I know I can write an .iso cross platform, but I'm looking for a way to burn those .ISOs to disk on a variety of platforms without having to code seperately for each one.

It's for burning MP3 disks and standard audio CDs...

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check UniBurner too